# Dynamic variable for a login redirection

Tags: php, redirect

I recently implemented in my website a File Manager (FileGator) that has a login/user system but i'm having some troubles trying to modify the redirection code. My login form is present on every page and currently a user logging in is automomatically redirected to the same page he was browsing.

Thing is there is one specific page where i want my user to be redirected elsewhere, so i came up with a code that actually works fine :

```
// reload
        if(isset($_REQUEST['redirect']) && ($_REQUEST['redirect'])!=='http://mywebsite.home/ftp/?login=1' )
            $url = $_REQUEST['redirect']; // holds url for last page visited.
        else {
            header('Location: '.gatorconf::get('base_url').'/?cd='); // default page 
            die;
        }
        header("Location:$url");
        die;
```

So with that code my user is always redirected to the same page exept if the url of the current page is `http://mywebsite.home/ftp/?login=1` in which case he will be redirected to the "default page" (which is also the pahe the user gets redirected if he logs in from the File Manager's login page).

But what i'd like is that url `http://mywebsite.home/ftp/?login=1` to be "dynamic" kinda like this : `"base_url"/ftp/?login=1` so that it works both on local and everywhere i upload it, it would also looks cleaner.

I tried using the File Manager's line of code `('Location: '.gatorconf::get('base_url').'/?cd=')`which seems to automatically get my base url.

What I tried :

```
// reload
    if(isset($_REQUEST['redirect']) && ($_REQUEST['redirect'])!==(.gatorconf::get('base_url')./?login=1) )
        $url = $_REQUEST['redirect']; // holds url for last page visited.
    else {
        header('Location: '.gatorconf::get('base_url').'/?cd='); // default page 
        die;
    }
    header("Location:$url");
    die;
}
```

also tried something with a $variable like :

```
// reload
        $default_redirect = .gatorconf::get('base_url').'/?login=1';
        if(isset($_REQUEST['redirect']) && ($_REQUEST['redirect'])!==($default_redirect) )
            $url = $_REQUEST['redirect']; // holds url for last page visited.
        else {
            header('Location: '.gatorconf::get('base_url').'/?cd='); // default page 
            die;
        }
        header("Location:$url");
        die;
    }
```

But as it is probably obvious by now i don't know much about php and can't find the right way to put it even after some researchs. Can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggle later i finally found the correct code for my problem :

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['redirect']) && ($_REQUEST['redirect']!==gatorconf::get('base_url').'/?login=1'))
```